# bloc how should I design it

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have a bloc which is fetching products using a repository for example `products_repository.getAllProducts()`. For that reason, in the bloc's state I have declared a List to assign the fetched products.

So far everything works fine.

Now, I want to implement an other bloc event that will fetch a product by id, for example `products_repository.getProductById(productId)`.

My question is should I use a new bloc to implement this? or I can reuse my bloc and add a new event to support it?

Comment: Maybe I will prefer using parameters while both  are fetching item

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a new event to do it.

```bash
abstract class ProductsEvent {}

//call when handle getAllProducts
class ProductsLoaded extends ProductsEvent {}

//call when handle getProductById
class ProductsByIdLoaded extends ProductsEvent {}
```

Comment: I tried this. But in my `ProductsState` I have a `List<Product>`. But if I want to reuse the ProductsState then I should also declare a Product object to save the product from the `getProductById()` and I am not sure this is a right approach

Comment: If i show a list on a UI screen, then you only use 1 List<Product> to update the UI according to the list. And If you need to save both then simply create a new List<Product> productsById inside the success state.
See more examples to understand better.
https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterinfinitelisttutorial

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same bloc and add a new event (even that's always not necessary).
Let me explain with an example.
Suppose you have a screen that shows a customer quote.
Against the customer quote, you show various buttons so that the user can take actions such as:

-----Actions on the document---------

- Send for approval
- Cancel
- Print
- Convert to a sales order
- etc

I would create a single event for all these actions, and the event would send a value (enum stating the action user has taken ). I would show the same progress indicator screen till the action is complete. Once the action is completed, I would emit a new state specifying whether the action was a success or failure.

However, I might emit a different event for a separate button (Profitability Analysis). Because now, while the action is in progress, I would want a different message. Like how many old orders I have fetched, what the cost was, etc.

So it all depends on what you want to show on screen. But definitely only one bloc!

Comment: I understand your approach. My question is, how I save the result of the `getProductById` in my state, since there, I have a `List<Product>` and not a `Product` object in order to save the product object from the `getProductById`. Should I declare a Product object aswell on my state? This doesnt look right to me. A state with a List<Product> and Product object declared

Comment: You can just create a local variable in your method and add the Product to the list. There is nothing inherently wrong with having 2 variables -  one product list and one product. There are many APIs that send limited information for a list (because lists are usually for display purposes). However, send more information (including entity definition - i.e what can be updated/deleted, etc) for a single entity.

Comment: I think you should just add one product to your state variable that is a list . This option is convenient for you as well since your state class doesn’t have to change . Any problems you have adding one product to the list ?